# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method. Guid causing trouble?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In my model class OwnedModule i have OwnerID as Guid.

There is another model class called BusinessUnit which contains the same Guid value from OwnedModule and its OwnerName.

I want to show the details of OwnedModule, which contains all the details about the hardware but has the owner as Guid value and not the name, and for this i have created a view model

```
public class OwnedModuleViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public string KindName { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public DateTime OwnershipStart { get; set; }
    }
    public class IndexOwnedModule
    {
        public List<OwnedModuleViewModel> OwnedModules { get; set; }
    }
```

to show all this detail in my repository i have following function

```
    public IndexOwnedModule GetAllOwnedModules()
    {

        var modulesList = new IndexOwnedModule();

        var modules = (_dbSis.OwnedModules.OrderBy(module => module.Id).Select(module => new OwnedModuleViewModel
        {
            Id = module.Id,
            ModuleId = module.ModuleId,
            TypeName = module.ModuleType.TypeName,
            Owner = GetModuleOwner(module.ModuleOwnerId),//error here
            OwnershipStart = module.Start
        }));

        modulesList.OwnedModules = modules.ToList();
        return modulesList;

    }

    public string GetModuleOwner(Guid id)
    {
        var ownedModule =_dbSis.Set<BusinessUnit>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
        if (ownedModule != null) return ownedModule.Name;
        return null;
    }
```

It would not be convinient to show the guid value as owner in the view to user so I wanted to fetch the name for which I had GetModuleOwnerName.

But it seems like the way i've set the name of the owner to my viewmodel view is wrong, and when i run the application i get the following error.

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetModuleOwner(System.Guid)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

When i comment the line where I've set the value of owner(**Owner = GetModuleOwner(module.ModuleOwnerId)**), everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Entity Framework build your query, it relies on the inspection of the passed Expression Tree. When it encounter a method call, it will try to map it to an equivalent SQL method using ([see this for the canonical methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)). Because Entity Framework has no knowledge of `OwnedModuleViewModel.GetModuleOwner`, it cannot generate an appropriate SQL query. In this case, the simple way would be to embed what your method does in the query instead of calling a method:

```
_dbSis.OwnedModules
      .OrderBy(module => module.Id)
      .Select(module => new OwnedModuleViewModel 
          {
              Id = module.Id,
              ModuleId = module.ModuleId,
              TypeName = module.ModuleType.TypeName,
              Owner = _dbSis.Set<BusinessUnit>()
                            .Where(t => t.Id == module.ModuleOwnerId)
                            .Select(t => t.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
              OwnershipStart = module.Start
          });
```

Of course, that is assuming `_dbSis.Set<BusinessUnit>()` is a `DbSet<T>` part of the same `DbContext`, otherwise the same problem arise.

Comment: this worked, but it would have been better to have Owner set by using method, doesn't make the code look clean

Comment: @Biplov13 If you have a relationship defined between `OwnerModule` and `BusinessUnit`, you can simply use the navigation property on `OwnerModule` to access `BusinessUnit` instead of doing an embedded select. But I can't say for sure without knowing how your model is defined.

Comment: unfortunately, there is not nagivation property, but thanks anyways

Comment: Not sure how nice the EF SQL generator will do with this query, or even if it will generate only one statement, or one statement for every row from `OwnedModules`

Comment: In my experience, EF SQL generator is very smart. I've tried clever, more complicated ways of doing things and always came back to simpler syntax. The query itself might look ugly (because it will essentially do an embedded select) but the SQL database is pretty smart at optimizing the query plan.

Comment: @SimonBelanger - unfortunately my experience has not been the same in some cases, although that was in EF 4.0, and I believe they have made a few improvements in query generation in the last few releases. With that said, this is a much simpler case than what I've encountered, so I'm sure you are right in this query performance will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Linq-To-Entities, a Linq statement against a context gets translated to a SQL statement. It's obviously impossible to translate the `GetModuleOwner()` method to SQL. You need to get the ModuleOwnerId first, and then in another step after, call GetModuleOwner() on each ModuleOwnerId.

Or you could restructure your query to use a join:

```
var modules = from m in _dbSis.OwnedModules
              join b in _dbSis.BusinessUnit on m.ModuleOwnerId equals b.Id
              order by m.Id
              select new OwnedModuleViewModel {
                                      Id = m.Id,
                                      ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
                                      TypeName = m.ModuleType.TypeName,
                                      Owner = b.Name,
                                      OwnershipStart = m.Start};

modulesList.OwnedModules = modules.ToList();
```

NOTE: I didn't test this so it might have some minor syntax errors.

Comment: I think it would work, minus (I think) the `OwnedModuleViewModel()`. You really need to stick with object initializer syntax with Entity Framework or it will complain.

Comment: Its good to see that the method I have is in fact being used, but i kinda feel is quite complex. Also like the minor error u said do exists, like editor says it is expecting **;** by the end of second line and it is not resolving the symbol **m** and **b** in select. Anyways thanks for the options

Answer (score 0):

This could be another option

```
var ownedModules = _dbSis.OwnedModules.OrderBy(module => module.Id).Select(module => new
            {
                Id = module.Id,
                ModuleId = module.ModuleId,
                TypeName = module.ModuleType.TypeName,
                ModuleOwnerId = module.ModuleOwnerId,
                OwnershipStart = module.Start
            }).ToList().Select(m => new OwnedModuleViewModel
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
                TypeName = m.TypeName,
                Owner = GetModuleOwner(m.ModuleOwnerId),
                OwnershipStart = m.OwnershipStart
            });
            ownedModulesList.OwnedModules = ownedModules.ToList();
            return ownedModulesList;
```

Comment: Uses the function and no complex queries as well

Comment: The problem with your new answer is its terribly ineffective. Embedding the method in the query allow the query to be done once. What you are proposing does one query to get the `OwnerModules`, and for every one of them, you send another query to get the Owner. If you have 5 modules, you do 6 queries. If you have 100 modules, you do 101 queries, etc.. While it does work, it doesn't scale well. And calling `ToList` creates an unnecessary temporary list. You can substitute it for `AsEnumerable` or replace the `Select` for `List<T>.ForEach` and change the materialized objects.

Comment: You are welcome. There are some quirks to using EF and the materialization (`IQueryable` vs `IEnumerable`) is one of them, unfortunately. :/